# Circle Drawing Algorithm

Tags: c, bgi

I have designed a circle algorithm which uses equation:
(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2

Here is a code::::

```
   #include<graphics.h>
  #include<math.h>
float rety(int x1,int r1,int a1,int b1)
{//function simulates (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2
 float tmp;
 tmp=(x1-a1)*(x1-a1);
 tmp=(r1*r1)-tmp;
 tmp=abs(tmp);
 tmp=sqrt(tmp);
 tmp=tmp+b1;
 return tmp;
}
void main()
{
 int tmp2,x=0,y=0,r=50,a=200,b=200,gm=DETECT,gd=DETECT;
 initgraph(&gm,&gd,"c://turboc3//bgi");
 x=a-r;//set x position as left most point of circle
 c1:
 y=rety(x,r,a,b);
 putpixel(x,y,5);//only draws half circle
 tmp2=y-b;
 putpixel(x,b-tmp2,5);//draw symmetric to above half circle
 x=x+1;
 if((x>a+r)==0){goto c1;}
}
```

Output:::::
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4kpKF0WrDOQUk9BSm55bjJ0Zm8/view?usp=docslist_api

refer the image and see the left and right side of circle is appearing dotted.

I just need help to improve algorithm so those blank spaces will completely get filled

Thanks in advance,
Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the Midpoint circle algorthm, as it is extremely efficient and has a fully integer-based version.  The following page contains a C code function...

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

EDIT:  However...

The problem with your algorithm as it stand is that you are ALWAYS incrementing x by 1 every iteration.  But you will sometimes need to draw multiple pixels at a same x coordinate, hence the gaps where the circle curve is almost vertical at the left and right sides.

Change your algorithm to **conditionally** increment x based on the y coordinate.

Comment: thats what i dont want.....i didn't understood mid point algo.It is efficient but i need to do it by my self....so i designed algo of my own.may be you understand what i am trying to say

Comment: right .... got it. ..thank you.....I'll update output after successful execution....... By the way i am doing it for my satisfaction